# knockout search issue Property 'model' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: durandal

how can i get it work ?

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout', 'services/logger', 'durandal/app', 'mapping', 'services/routeconfig', 'services/dataBindingHandlers'], function (router, ko, logger, app, mapping, routeconfig, dataBindingHandlers) {

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log('Übersicht View Activated', null, 'newSearch', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
    //==jquery=================================================
    function attached() {

    }//-->end of attached() 


    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the+Cat+In+The+Hat", path = $.getJSON(url);


    path.then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.items);
        var viewModel = {
            title: 'Overview',
            query: ko.observable('')
        };
        viewModel.activate = activate();
        viewModel.attached = attached();
        viewModel.model = mapping.fromJS(data.items, {}, viewModel);
        /*understanding ko.mapping.fromJS signature:knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data) - this syntax will create view model.
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions) - this will create view model with particular options.
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, viewModel) -
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel) -
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel) - and this one convers your data without mapping options and put it to view model.
        */
        viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
            var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
                alert("i'am here in viewModel.books computed");
                console.log(viewModel.model);
                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.model(), function (book) {
                    return book.id().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 || book.kind().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 || book.etag().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0
                });

        }, viewModel);
        return viewModel;
    });

});
```

[Utility Functions in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

**UPDATES:**  i recieve a loop of objects when i console.log(viewModel.model);

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't clearly stated what it is that doesn't work about it?

However, you probably need to add the activate and attached methods to the viewModel in order for them to be called by durandal.

```
viewModel.activate = activate;
viewModel.attached = attached;
```

You probably also intend this chunk of code to be called within the activate function and not in the define call:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the+Cat+In+The+Hat",path =$.getJSON(url);

path.then( function (data) {
var books = data.items;
    console.log(books);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined  but in viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(books);  data.items is define i can see it in the console too i make some updates based on your answer and that s the error i recieve

Comment: I think that the ko.mapping is a plugin that needs to be loaded in addition to knockout http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: i changed it to viewModel.model = mapping.fromJS(books, {}, viewModel); but now it says model is not a function  after the  console.log("i'am here in viewModel.books computed"); i make an update of the viewmodel